# Is it possible to run a R script from Java

Tags: java, r

I have a script in R (MyScript.R) which i want to execute by calling it from Java, passing the .csv file as the input. I do not want to use Rcaller.addCode("some r code") to add one line at a time.

Which R interface should i use for this (JRI/Rcaller/JRG/Rserve) and How ?

Answer (score 1):

Refer these links

https://code.google.com/p/renjin/wiki/CallingRFromJava

[calling R script from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844451/calling-r-script-from-java)

http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~lpekelis/13_datafest_cart/13_datafest_r_talk.html