# not able to execute R script from java program?

Tags: java, r, bash, runtime, processbuilder

I have a Rscript in a String variable and I want to execute it from Java program and pass some variable to it. If I execute that R script standalone, it works fine. I have converted that R script to one line by escaping it everything by using Python program as shown below:

```
import json

jsonstr = json.dumps({"script": """\
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

# read the data file
library('jsonlite')
library('rpart')

args <- as.list(Sys.getenv(c(
                        "path",
                        "client_users")))

if (args[["path"]]==""){
    args[["path"]] <- "."
}

# other stuff here
# other stuff here

"""})

print jsonstr
```

I use the printed string out and store it in String variable and then I am executing with below code and it doesn't work at all. I am passing `path` and `client_users` variable to above R script.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    // this is your script in a string
    // String script = "#!/bin/bash\n\necho \"Hello World\"\n\n readonly PARAM1=$param1\n echo $PARAM1\n\nreadonly PARAM2=$param2\n echo $PARAM2\n\n";
    String script = "above R Script here";

    List<String> commandList = new ArrayList<>();
    commandList.add("/bin/bash");

    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(commandList);
    builder.environment().put("path", "/home/david");
    builder.environment().put("client_users", "1000");
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process shell = builder.start();

    // Send your script to the input of the shell, something
    // like doing cat script.sh | bash in the terminal
    try(OutputStream commands = shell.getOutputStream()) {
        commands.write(script.getBytes());
    }

    // read the outcome
    try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(shell.getInputStream()))) {
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }

    // check the exit code
    int exitCode = shell.waitFor();
    System.out.println("EXIT CODE: " + exitCode);
}
```

Above code works fine with bash shell script. Is there anything I need to do special for R script? I will be using same code for bash script and R scripts as well.

And this is the error I am getting:

```
/bin/bash: line 7: -: No such file or directory /bin/bash: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `'jsonlite'' /bin/bash: line 10: `library('jsonlite')'
```

And if I remove `commandList.add("/bin/bash");` and add `commandList.add("/bin/Rscript");` then I see below error:

```
Cannot run program "/bin/Rscript": error=2, No such file or directory
```

**Update:-**

Instead of using my above script, I decided to use simple print hell script in r to see whether I can execute it through Java or not.

```
// this will print hello
String script = "#!/usr/bin/env Rscript\nsayHello <- function(){\n   print('hello')\n}\n\nsayHello()\n";
```

When I execute this script with `commandList.add("/bin/bash");`, I get this error:

```
/bin/bash: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: line 2: `sayHello <- function(){'
```

But if I execute with this `commandList.add("/bin/sh");`, I get this error:

```
/bin/sh: 2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to run `/usr/bin/Rscript` directly. Also, this program doesn't read scripts from the standard input (you have to specify the path to the script as an argument for `Rscript`), so you will have to:

- Create a temp file
- Write your script
- Execute your script with Rscript
- Delete your temp file (as a good programming practice)

As an example, this is a POC:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    // Your script
    String script = "#!/usr/bin/env Rscript\n" +
            "\n" +
            "sayHello <- function() {\n" +
            "    print('hello')\n" +
            "}\n" +
            "\n" +
            "sayHello()\n";

    // create a temp file and write your script to it
    File tempScript = File.createTempFile("test_r_scripts_", "");
    try(OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(tempScript)) {
        output.write(script.getBytes());
    }

    // build the process object and start it
    List<String> commandList = new ArrayList<>();
    commandList.add("/usr/bin/Rscript");
    commandList.add(tempScript.getAbsolutePath());
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(commandList);
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process shell = builder.start();

    // read the output and show it
    try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(shell.getInputStream()))) {
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }

    // wait for the process to finish
    int exitCode = shell.waitFor();

    // delete your temp file
    tempScript.delete();

    // check the exit code (exit code = 0 usually means "executed ok")
    System.out.println("EXIT CODE: " + exitCode);
}
```

As an alternative, **and if your script has a "shebang" as the first line**, you could do these changes:

- set its executable attribute to "true"
- use the path to the temp file as first element in the commandList (i. e. delete `commandList.add("/usr/bin/Rscript");`)

the part of the code to be modified would be:

```
...

// create a temp file and write your script to it
File tempScript = File.createTempFile("test_r_scripts_", "");
tempScript.setExecutable(true);
try(OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(tempScript)) {
    output.write(script.getBytes());
}

// build the process object and start it
List<String> commandList = new ArrayList<>();
commandList.add(tempScript.getAbsolutePath());
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(commandList);

...
```