# Running an R-Program from Java

Tags: java, r

I got following simple R-program named *hello.R*:

```
print('hello')
```

I like to call this code from Java now.
This is my code in Java:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\hello.R";
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.1.3\\bin\\Rscript "+path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }

}
```

I was expecting it to print the hello statement in the Java concole. But Java program didn't do anything at all.

Do you know what the problem may be?

Comment: You are concatenating an absolute path (`path`) with another absolute path in `Runtime.exec()` - even without a path separator!

Comment: I got this hint from a different post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844451/calling-r-script-from-java

Comment: Yes, my bad, I am sorry. Did not notice the space and that you are actually calling the interpreter with the `path` as argument.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936023/printing-runtime-exec-outputstream-to-console/12200361#12200361) I think you should do the following:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/path/to/Rscript", "/path/to/hello.r");
pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);
pb.redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);
Process p = pb.start();
```

This redirects both the output stream and the error stream of the subprocess to the current process, allowing you to observe the contents in the Java console.

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately I get an error message: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.3\bin\Rscript C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\hello.R": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
 at Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
 ... 2 more

Comment: There was a mistake in my code example (the command and its argument need to be separated), I updated my answer.

Comment: Are you sure that the paths you used are correct? You can try the command using Windows command line CMD (assuming you run Windows)?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following to get the hello string in Java:

```
#* @get /hello
hello <- function() {
  print("hello")
}
```

You can run the following:

```
library(plumber)
r <- plumb("hello.R")
r$run(port=8080)
```

If you then call the page

```
http://localhost:8080/hello
```

your R code will be executed.

If you want to execute it from Java the solution could be:

```
   URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/hello");
   URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( (connection.getInputStream())));
   String result = br.readLine();
```